# Number of faces of convex hull

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

If you have $n$ points in $d$-dimensional Euclidean space, the number of faces of the convex hull is potentially exponential I understand. How can this be proved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example: Consider the $2d$ points $\pm e_i$, where $(e_1,\ldots, e_d)$ is the standard basis of ${\mathbb R}^d$. Their convex hull $C^d$ is a "generalized octahedron", called *crosspolytope*:
$$C^d=\left\{{\bf x}\in{\mathbb R}^d\ \biggm|\ \sum_{i=1}^d |x_i|\leq1\right\}\ .$$
$C^2$ is a square with sidelength $\sqrt{2}$, $C^3$ an octahedron. In general $C^d$ has $2^d$ simplicial facets, corresponding to the $2^d$ possible choices of the sign when choosing $+e_i$ or $-e_i$ for $1\leq i\leq d$ as vertices of a facet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that can be proved the converse, because the convex hull of a subset $A$ of $d$-dimensional Euclidean space is a union of $d$-dimensional simplexes with vertices from $A$, by Carathéodory Theorem; so your set is a union of no greater than $\binom n{d+1}$ simplexes. :-)

Comment: $n$-choose-$d+1$ is exponential when $n$ and $d$ are proportional!